# Как реализовать событие hover для динамических элементов jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Данные конструкции не работают:

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".selector", function () {}
$(document).on("hover", ".selector", function () {}
$("*").on("mouseover", ".selector", function () {}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#test').on('click', function() {
    $("<a>", { class: 'selector', 
               title: 'my title',
               text: 'Text' }).appendTo(document.body);
  });
  
  $(document).on("mouseenter", ".selector", function () {
    console.log('работает!');
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='test'>clickme!</button>
```